# Concatenation using javascript' script from php

Tags: php, javascript, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a php array into javascript array.
And use all of this to create jquery function.
Help me...

Instructions for in the loop are => descriptif[i] = .$description[i].;

```
    <?php echo '<script> var descriptif = new Array (); 
                for(i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)
                {
                    descriptif[i] = "'.$description["'"+ i +"'"].'";
                }   
                </script>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're thinking about:

```
<script> var descriptif = new Array (); 
<?php for(i=0 ; i<16 ; i++) {
    echo "descriptif[$i] = '$description[$i]';"
} ?>
</script>
```

It will print:

```
<script> var descriptif = new Array (); 
    descriptif[0] = value1;
    descriptif[1] = value2;
    descriptif[2] = value3;
    ...
</script>
```

PS if you want to dynamize something (javascript, css ,etc.) with a scripting language (php, jsp), use , <% %> only in the parts that differ (the loop part). The rest is the same so it doesn't have to be echoed - it makes your code less clear.

Comment: My concatenation  is the problem. id dont know how to concatenate this thing ... i am lost...

Comment: SEDZ ... YOU ROCK, THANKX.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access PHP arrays using client-side Javascript.

- PHP is a ***server***-side language. Everything happens on the server.
- Javascript is a ***client***-side language. Everything happens in the browser.

Comment: You're right. But @user2102302 could need dynamically built javascript. Once javascript is generated by PHP, it cannot be changed.

Comment: "Could". I am just working on what I have. Looking at the code s/he seems to be inter-mingling PHP and Javascript. If they want a good answer then they need to write a good question.

Comment: This is not an answer, I think you need to remove it

Comment: Thankx for so quick answers. My concatenation